# Are laravel's routes safeguarding enough against file traversal attacks?

Tags: laravel, security

```
Route::get('/transaction/{name}', 'TransactionController@download');


public function download($name){
    $path = storage_path('app/something/') . $name . '.xml';
    return response()->download($path);
}
```

The user shall using this action only be able to download .xml files in app/something.

Is it possible to to download data outside of the specified `app/something` folder.

Comment: What do you mean with "exploit"? Someone can DDoS the heck out your app without downloading 1 file.

Comment: I mean only to download data outside of the specific app/something folder.

Comment: Great question @Alex!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know Laravel will compile your path to:

```
#^/transaction/(?P<name>[^/]++)$#s
```

So simple / will not not work.. 
You could use more sophisticated backslash - but it depends on server..

At the end - Remember not to trust all user input.. No matter does it goes through routing or received directly..

Answer (score 2):

Laravel doesn't protect against traversal attacks - the router will return any value with your code example, meaning that someone could get access to your filesystem!

You an use PHP's `basename()` to sanitise `$name` by removing any path references from the string:

```
Route::get('/transaction/{name}', 'TransactionController@download');


public function download($name){
    $path = storage_path('app/something/') . basename($name, '.xml') . '.xml';
    return response()->download($path);
}
```

Comment: But how can I supply `..` and `/` to the `$name` from?

Comment: I think you need to re-think your logic - you shouldn't allow people navigating your website the ability to know anything about your filesystem. If they need to download a file from a different directory then you should create another route. Another way of doing things is to create a database table where you can access a file's location from it's filename and use that to determine where it's been saved. Or the files should be stored completely statically away from your Laravel app.

Comment: No - misunderstanding. I am thinking from the attacker's point of view here: How could he supply a `..` or `/` to the `$name` variable to do directory traversal.

Comment: he can easily surf to www.yourapp.com/transaction/../../../../../../etc/passwd. In this case that won't do a lot because you are appending `.xml` but it's still bad practice.

Comment: I think the basename function prevents the directory traversal. So the code by @edcs prevents the attack

Comment: Yes, I think so as well that basename() prevents it - but I am not sure if it is a real attack vector - call `www.yourapp.com/transaction/../../foo/bar`did not work for me if there is a `bar.xml`

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer**

As you can see below, it's definitely possible to do malicious stuff within Laravel routes. Given your function setup, the chance of someone doing something you don't want is small, because he/she can only alter the `$name` variable.

You can still write some extra code like this (found on [viblo.asia](https://viblo.asia/yasin/posts/NPVMaDygRQOk)):

```
$basepath = '/foo/bar/baz/';        // Path to xml file
$realBase = realpath($basepath);

$userpath = $basepath . $_GET['path'];
$realUserPath = realpath($userpath);

if ($realUserPath === false || strpos($realUserPath, $realBase) !== 0) {
    //Directory Traversal!
} else {
    //Good path!
}
```

To prevent users from accessing files they aren't allowed to.

---

**Old, but relevant answer**

Just tried this in Homestead:

```
Route::get(
    '/',
    function () {
        dump(exec('ls ' . storage_path() . '/../../../'));
    }
);
```

And that prints the corresponding folder just fine:

[image]

So I'd say that it's definitely possible to do stuff outside of the specified folder. Try this for yourself for example:

```
Route::get(
    '/',
    function () {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            $path = str_repeat('/..', $i);
            dump(exec('ls ' . storage_path() . $path));
        }
    }
);
```

And see your folders appear on screen when you hit the `/` route.

Comment: there is parameter $name. i think op want to know if this parameter can be hacked.